# How could a logarithmically changing graph be made that exists only between asymptotes at x= 0 and 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I came up with this problem as a simple thought experiment, but quickly found that it would not be so easy to solve. I managed to come up with these four separate functions that showed some of the properties I wanted, put together making the whole graph. I noticed that each function is very similar to the others, and am convinced that there must be a way to write the four functions as one.
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-10^{\log_2 (0.5/x)-1},  & 0\le x\le 0.25 \\
-10^{\log_2 (-8(x-0.5))-1},  & 0.25\le x\le 0.5 \\
10^{\log_2 (8(x-0.5))-1},  & 0.5\le x\le 0.75 \\
10^{\log_2 (-0.5/(x-1))-1},  & 0.75\le x\le 1
\end{cases}
$$
The only parameters are, there must be vertical asymptotes at $x=0$ and $x=1,$ when $x=0.5,$ $y=0,$ the $y$ value must increase/decrease multiplying by ten each time the x value becomes $50\%$ closer to $1$ and $0$ respectively. It should also approach $(0.5,0)$ from both directions in a similar manner.

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY6pc.png)

[Corresponding Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJNcX.png)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the so-called ["logit" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), which is the inverse of a Sigmoidal function. This family of functions is very useful for statistical and machine learning applications. One example is $f(x) = \log\frac{x}{1-x}$, and of course more functions can be obtained simply by scaling to $f(x) = \log\frac{ax}{1-x}$.

Comment: Though this strategy does fit some of the more important parameters of the problem, one of the more important ones it misses is the logarithmic increase of the y value. I did try to change the function in order to account for that, but only ended up finding the four separate functions I already have.